# Как добавить стейт на проверку бана?

Tags: reactjs

Как добавить еще один стейт, который будет показывать, забанен пользователь или нет.
Вывестить информацию об этом в каком-нибудь теге?

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
    let [user, setUser] = React.useState();

    return <div>
        <span>{user}</span>
        <button onClick={() => setUser('Alekosh')}>btn1</button>
        <button onClick={() => setUser('Ambrose')}>btn2</button>

        
    </div>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `const [isBanned, setIsBanned] = useState(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    username: "lol",
    isBanned: false,
  });

return (
    <>
      <span>{user.isBanned ? "Забанен" : "Бана нет"}</span>
      <button onClick={() => setUser({ username: "Alekosh", isBanned: false })}>
        btn1
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setUser({ username: "Ambrose", isBanned: true })}>
        btn2
      </button>

      
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```